# Run Function to animate content on .load complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

I've built a site using the History API in modernizr that includes CSS3 page transitions for smooth loading. This is the code for that.

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
  var isAnimating = false,
  firstLoad   = false;

  $('.menu a').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var newPage = $(this).attr('href');
if( !isAnimating ) changePage(newPage, true);
firstLoad = true;
  });

  $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
if(firstLoad) {
  var newPageArray = location.pathname.split('/'),
    newPage = newPageArray[newPageArray.length - 1];
  if( !isAnimating ) changePage(newPage, false);
}
firstLoad = true;
  });

  function changePage(url, bool) {
  isAnimating = true;
  $('body').addClass('page-is-changing').removeClass('show-menu');
  $('#open-button').removeClass('open');
  $('.loader').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
  loadNewContent(url, bool);
  $('.loader').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
});
if(!transitionsSupported()) loadNewContent(url, bool);
  }

  function loadNewContent(url, bool) {
url = ('' == url) ? 'index.html' : url;
var section = $('<div class="content-wrap"></div>');

//$.getScript('#page-script', function(){});

console.log(url);

section.load(url + ' .content-wrap > *', function(event){
  $('.wrapper').html(section);

  var delay = ( transitionsSupported() ) ? 1200 : 0;

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').removeClass('page-is-changing').remove('#page-script').load('#page-script');
    $('.loader').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
      isAnimating = false;
      $('.loader').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
    });
    if( !transitionsSupported() ) isAnimating = false;
  }, delay);

  if(url!=window.location && bool){
    window.history.pushState({path: url},'', url);
  }
});
  }

  function transitionsSupported() {
return $('html').hasClass('csstransitions');
  }
```

What I wanted to know is how would I call a function on completion of the loadNewContent function? I'd like to animate the content in from each page, but I need it to wait to fire until the content loads.

Thanks!
Jesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using jQuery's .promise() and .done()

```
$('example').fadeOut().promise().done(function(){
 // code here executes when the animation is finished.
});
```

Adding here that .load() has a callback like so :

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

More info : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks. How would I integrate this at the completion of the .load()?